# How do I check HTTP headers of an incoming request to Google Appengine in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an app installed on Google Appengine running on Python code. It has a request handler and a built-in database, which I update via something like this:

http://appname.appspot.com/?type=update&service=test_name&url=..........

I only want the database to update, if the client accessing the python app has a certain HTTP header, and bounce all other requests. How do I request a list of the HTTP headers and check if the list contains a certain header string within?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_headers

Basically

```
self.request.headers
```

is a dictionary-like object that holds the request headers.

Answer (score 1):

within your handler [`self.request`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_headers) holds all the request info, including headers.